# jquery form plugin does not working

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

i am a newbie programmer.I am stuck for two days with a simple code.I try to use jquery form plugin for submitting a form to another page and get a feedback from that page.The problem is the plugin is not working.the form is submitted as normaly without feedback.Here is the code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<div id='preview'></div>
<form  action='ajaxcall.php' id='upload_pic' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
<input type='file' id='pic' name='picture'>
<input type='submit' id='sub'>
</form>

var options=
{
target:'#preview',
url:'ajaxcall.php'


};

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sub").click(function(){
    $('#preview').html("<img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Loading.....'/>");
    $('#upload_pic').ajaxForm(options).submit();
    });
});
```

Here is my ajaxcall.php page code

```
 if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['size']))
 {
echo "<img src='images/197.jpg'>";

 }
```

Expectation was the echoed image would feddback but the page is simply redirected to ajaxcall.php page.ajaxForm() function is not working.But why?please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your submit button for a normal one, because you are already submiting the form programatically from your click handler, so replace your following html:

```
<input type='submit' id='sub'>
```

for this one:

```
<input type='button' id='sub'>
```

Comment: Alright, the solution seems to be a bit different, check out my updated answer.

Comment: And remember to mark answer as accepted (mark the check under the question score) if this finally work for you :-)

Comment: still redirected to ajaxcall.php page.If your solution work for you it also work for me.whats the problem.help please.

Answer (score 0):

use these codes instead of your script codes. sorry for the late answer

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sub").click(function(){
       var options=
       {
          target:'#preview',
          url:'ajaxcall.php' 
       };
       $('#preview').html("<img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Loading.....'/>");
       $('#upload_pic').ajaxForm(options).submit();

    });
});
```